# Get data.frame row by ID

Tags: r

I have a data.frame $X$ obtained from a data.frame $Y$ by filtering out some rows. 
I am now interested in accessing a row with ID $i$ (By ID I mean the value appearing in the very first column, generated by R). I am only aware of the $X[i,]$ command, which, as far as I understand, gives me the $i$-th row in $X$ but not the row with ID $i$.

Is there any other command to access a row by its id?

Comment: This should be asked on StackOverflow given that there's no statistical question.

Comment: You could use `row.names(X)` to access the ID information.

Comment: @John Sorry I will post these questions on SO in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `row.names(X)` to access the ID information. Example is given below.

```
X <- subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(Ozone, Temp))
X$id <- row.names(X)
head(X)
        #   Ozone Temp id
        #29    45   81 29
        #35    NA   84 35
        #36    NA   85 36
        #38    29   82 38
        #39    NA   87 39
        #40    71   90 40
X[X$id==35,]
        #   Ozone Temp id
        #35    NA   84 35
```

Comment: Or even `X[row.names(X)==35,]` if it's a one-off.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, you can use quotes `""` to refer to a given row by its respective element of `rownames()`,e.g.:

```
X["35",]
```